# Java, Creating an insert function for a LinkedList to add all inserted elements in ascending order

Tags: java, insert, linked-list

I have to create a linked List class from scratch for my Java project which will insert a date Object into its proper position. My format for sorting is to simply keep the year/month/day as a single string for use in comparing two Date objects. My compareTo function seems to not be the source of the problem as a simple selectionSort test yielded the proper result. My insert is simply using only the first element to compare to all the rest which is not correct. I don't know how to fix the situation after tinkering with it for some time now.

```
public class Date212 {
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int year;

    public Date212(String d){

        String temp;
        temp = d.substring(4,6);
        int theMonth = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        temp = d.substring(6,8);
        int theDay = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        temp = d.substring(0,4);
        int theYear = Integer.parseInt(temp);

        setDate212(theYear, theMonth, theDay);
    }
    public void setDate212(int y, int m, int d){
        year = y;
        month = m;
        day = d;


    }

    public int getMonth(){
        return month;
    }
    public int getDay(){
        return day;
    }
    public int getYear(){
        return year;
    }

    public int compareTo(Date212 other){
        if(this.toString().compareTo( ((Date212)other).toString()) < 0)
            return -1; //This temp is smaller
         else if(this.toString().compareTo( ((Date212)other).toString()) > 0){
            return 1; //This temp is bigger
        }
        return 0; //Must be equal
    }

    public String toString(){
        String s = Integer.toString(year) + "/" + Integer.toString(month) + "/" + Integer.toString(day);
        return s;
    }           

}
```

```
public class ListNode
{
   protected Date212 data;
   protected ListNode next;

   public ListNode(Date212 d)
   {
      data = d;
      next = null;
   }  // constructor
}  // class ShortNode
```

```
public class LinkedList {

/** First node in linked list - dummy node */
private ListNode first = new ListNode(null);

/** Last node in linked list */
private ListNode last = first;

/** Number of data items in the list. */
private int length = 0;

/**
 * Gets the number of data values currently stored in this LinkedList.
 * 
 * @return the number of elements in the list.
 */

public int getLength() {
    return length;
}

/**
 * Appends a String data element to this LinkedList.
 * 
 * @param data
 *            the data element to be appended.
 */
public void append(Date212 d) {
    ListNode n = new ListNode(d);
    last.next = n;
    last = n;
    length++;
} // method append(String)

/**
 * Prepends (adds to the beginning) a String data element to this
 * LinkedList.
 * 
 * @param data
 *            the data element to be prepended.
 */
public void insert(Date212 d) {
    ListNode n = new ListNode(d);
    if (length == 0) //If your list is empty
    {
        last = n;
        first.next = n;
        n.next = null;
        length++;
    }
    else //There is element
    {
        ListNode p = first.next; //Start with the first element
        for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
            if(p.data.compareTo(d) < 0){ //If you are smaller than the *following* element
                n.next = p.next; //Insert the element after the actual
                p.next = n;
                return; //Return early
            }
            p = p.next;
        }
        //We are greater than any element
        this.append(d);
    }
    }


/**
 * Determines whether this ShortSequenceLinkedList is equal in value to the
 * parameter object. They are equal if the parameter is of class
 * ShortSequenceLinkedList and the two objects contain the same short
 * integer values at each index.
 * 
 * @param other
 *            the object to be compared to this ShortSequenceLinkedList
 * 
 * @return <code>true</code> if the parameter object is a
 *         ShortSequenceLinkedList containing the same numbers at each index
 *         as this ShortSequenceLinkedList, <code>false</code> otherwise.
 */
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == null || getClass() != other.getClass()
            || length != ((LinkedList) other).length)
        return false;

    ListNode nodeThis = first;
    ListNode nodeOther = ((LinkedList) other).first;
    while (nodeThis != null) {
        // Since the two linked lists are the same length,
        // they should reach null on the same iteration.

        if (nodeThis.data != nodeOther.data)
            return false;

        nodeThis = nodeThis.next;
        nodeOther = nodeOther.next;
    } // while

    return true;
} // method equals
public String printList(){
    String s = "";
    ListNode p = first.next;

    while(p != null){
            s += p.data.toString() + "\n";
            p = p.next;
        }
        return s;

}
 }// class LinkedList
```

Comment: Where is your `insert()` method?

Comment: 3rd method in linkedList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insertion code scans up to the number of nodes recorded as the list length.  That's not necessarily wrong in itself, but it would be better to just use nodes' `next` references to determine when you've reached the end.  One reason using `next` would be better is that your code would be less brittle: if, say, it failed to properly manage the list length when a node was inserted before the end, then the insertion code itself would still mostly work.

Here's an alternative way your code could be written:

```
public void insert(Date212 d) {
    ListNode n = new ListNode(d);
    ListNode p = first;

    // Find the insertion point
    while ((p.next != null) && (p.next.data.compareTo(d) < 0)) {
        p = p.next;
    }

    // Insert the node
    n.next = p.next;
    p.next = n;

    if (n.next == null) {
        last = n;
    }

    // Update the list length
    length++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of insert at the right position I think it would be easier insert the element on the list and after sort the list like Collections.sort(myList,myComparator) does.

Answer (score 0):

In a singly linked list, insertion requires a reference to the node **after** which the element is to be inserted. So we start with p = first, and traverse the list until we find a p.next which is **greater** than the element to be inserted. This means we should insert our new element after p and before p.next. This is achieved using a slightly modified version of your code as seen below.
Please note that this is for a list sorted in ascending order. For one sorted in descending order, it would be if(p.next.data.compareTo(d)<0) inside the for loop.

```
else //There is element
    {
        ListNode p = first; //Start with the head, p will point to the element AFTER which insertion should take place
        for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
            if(p.next.data.compareTo(d) > 0){ //If ele to insert is lesser than next ele
                n.next = p.next; //Insert the element after the actual
                p.next = n;
                length++;
                return; //Return early
            }
            p = p.next;
        }
        //We are greater than any element
        this.append(d);
    }
```

Comment: This misses the nature of the problem.

Comment: How so? The problem occurred for two reasons: the original code was inserting the node at the wrong position, and the wrong comparison was being used in the if statement. I believe I've addressed both in my answer. I've also chosen to modify the OP's code itself rather than writing new code so he knows where he's gone wrong and how to correct himself, important aspects of learning to write your own algorithm.

Comment: The problem in the original code was that it looped over `length` nodes at most, but did not update `length` when it inserted nodes before the end.  Hence the observed behavior of "using only the first element to compare to all the rest" (which, granted, is not very clearly worded).  *That's* what the question was *about*, regardless of any other issues the original code may have had.  Your answer still contains that essential bug.

Comment: I have, however, removed my downvote because you did point out a bona fide issue.

Comment: I just noticed - my apologies. I've edited my answer to reflect the changes. Thankyou for pointing that out. That wasn't the only bug in the OP's code, though. The if condition used p.data instead of p.next.data, which meant that if Node 1 was lesser than Node 2, it would still get inserted after Node 2, in a list in ascending order.

Comment: Thankyou :) my bad on the length though.